# PostgreSQL primary key auto increment crashes in C++

Tags: c++, sql, postgresql, key, auto-increment

What is the correct syntax to create an integer primary key auto incremental field in PostgreSQL using C++?

I started with

```
db->ExecuteSQL("CREATE TABLE mytable (\"mytableid\" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
```

This compiles but the process crashes and no field is created.

```
db->ExecuteSQL("CREATE TABLE mytable (\"mytableid\" serial PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
```

This works and does create the field correctly.

Do I need the `NOT NULL` or is this not necessary with `serial`?
Is this the best syntax and method in Postgres for primary key field creation?

Answer (score 5):

You do not need the `NOT NULL`. It is implied when you define the column [`PRIMARY KEYS`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-constraints.html). Per documentation:

> Technically, a primary key constraint is simply a combination of a
>   unique constraint and a not-null constraint.

In addition, [`serial` also implies NOT NULL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL). It's not a data type per se, just a notational convenience for `integer NOT NULL` with an attached sequence.

So this is perfect syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (mytableid serial PRIMARY KEY);
```

You don't need to double quote the column name as long as you don't want to use mixed case [identifiers](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html), [reserved words](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html) or "illegal" characters. I would advise to use legal, lower case identifiers exclusively to make your code less error-prone (and your life simpler).