# Check for complete duplicate rows in a large table

Tags: sql, postgresql, exists, duplicates, postgresql-8.1

My original question with all the relevant context can be found here:
[Adding a multi-column primary key to a table with 40 million records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17088747/adding-a-multi-column-primary-key-to-a-table-with-40-million-records)

I have a table with 40 million rows and no primary key. Before I add the primary key, I would like to check if the table has any duplicate entries. When I say duplicate entries, I don't just mean duplicate on particular columns. I mean duplicates on entire rows.

I was told in my last question that I can do an `EXISTS` query to determine duplicates. How would I do that?

I am running PostgreSQL 8.1.22. (Got this info by running `select version()`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find whether ***any*** full duplicate exists (identical on all columns), this is probably the fastest way:

```
SELECT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM   tbl t
    NATURAL JOIN tbl t1 
    WHERE  t.ctid <> t1.ctid
    )
```

`NATURAL JOIN` is a very convenient shorthand for the case because (quoting [the manual here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM)):

> `NATURAL` is shorthand for a `USING` list that mentions all columns in the
>   two tables that have the same names.

[**`EXISTS`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS) is probably fastest, because Postgres stops searching as soon as the first duplicate is found. Since you most probably don't have an index covering the whole row and your table is huge, this will save you *a lot* of time.

Be aware that **`NULL`** is *never* considered identical to another `NULL`. If you have `NULL` values and consider them identical, you'd have to do more.

[`ctid` is a system column](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-system-columns.html) that can be (ab-)used as ad-hoc primary key, but cannot replace an actual user-defined primary key in the long run.

---

The outdated version 8.1 seems to have no `<>` operator defined for a `ctid`. Try casting to `text`:

```
SELECT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM   tbl t
    NATURAL JOIN tbl t1 
    WHERE  t.ctid::text <> t1.ctid::text
    )
```

Comment: I am getting an error: ERROR:  operator does not exist: tid <> tid
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You may need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: @user1338584: Another problem with the outdated version. Once again: you really need an upgrade .. I added a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't something like that do the job?

```
SELECT ALL_COLUMNS[expect unique ID],
       count(0) as Dupl 
FROM   table 
WHERE  Dupl>1
GROUP BY ALL_COLUMNS[expect unique ID];
```

not sure if its the most efficient way, but count>1 means you have two identical rows.